# Dividing Modified Bessel function of the second kind at x=0

Tags: bessel-functions

I have to prove that

$\frac{K_l^2(0)}{K_{l+1}(0) K_{l-1}(0)} = 1 - \frac{1}{l}\quad \text{for} \quad  l \ge 2 $

Where $K_l$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind and $l$ is the order. I'm having trouble figuring out how this gives a non-zero or non-infinite result since $K$ diverges to infinity when $ x \rightarrow 0$. I have looked into expanding it into series but I couldn't end up with anything meaningful, so some help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the limiting form from https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.30.E2
$$K_{l}\left(z\right)\sim\tfrac{1}{2}\Gamma\left(l \right)(\tfrac{1}{2}z)^{-l}$$
for $z \to 0$ and get 
$$\frac{K_l^2(z)}{K_{l+1}(z) K_{l-1}(z)} \sim$$
$$\frac{\Big(\Gamma(l)(\tfrac{1}{2} z)^l\Big)^2}
{\Gamma(l-1)(\tfrac{1}{2}z)^{l-1}\cdot\Gamma(l+1)(\tfrac{1}{2}z)^{l+1}}=
\frac{\Gamma(l)^2}{\Gamma(l-1)\Gamma(l+1)} = \frac{l-1}{l}=1 -\frac{1}{l}$$